# Duplicate nodes with positive value in Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct Node {
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
struct List {
    Node* first; 
};
void duplicatePositiveNodes(List* list) {
    Node* current = new Node();
    Node* tmp = new Node();
    current = list->first;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->data > 0) {
            tmp->data = current->data;
            tmp->next = current->next;
            current->next = tmp;
            current = current->next->next;
        }
        else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    Print(list->first);
}
```

So, for example I have a linked list -> {1,0,-2,3,-4} , I wanna receive back this list-> {1,1,0,-2,3,3,-4}.

With my current code, I am receiving  back {1,3,-4}

After debugging, I realized that the problem is in the second iteration of this block of code ( i think, I messed up with pointers or etc)

```
 tmp->next = current->next;
            current->next = tmp;
```

Thanks for any help)

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for `current` and then immediately leaking it 2 lines later?

Comment: Your list has 100,000,000 nodes. Half of them are positive. How many new nodes do you need? How many new nodes do you allocate?

Comment: So I have to allocate a new node in each iteration with a positive value, and insert it into the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code. Stepping through it with a debugger is a good way to figure out where your code is not doing what you expect.

Here's a simple way to duplicate the nodes, as needed:

```
void duplicatePositiveNodes(List* list) 
{
  for(auto current = list->first; current; current = current-> next)
    if (current->data > 0)
    {
      current->next = new Node{current->data, current->next};
      current = current->next;  // to avoid infinite duplicates
    }
  
  Print(list->first);
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks so much, it is working properly. But can You still show me my errors in my code, to understand what I did wrong there?

Comment: @RomaRoik There are several issues in your code. See the comments yon your post for at least 2 issues. The best way is to learn how to use a debugger, so you can find out for yourself.